# Can Docker Swarm scale up/down hosts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm, amazon-ecs

I am fairly new to Docker Swarm and ECS. After briefly reading through the Docker Swarm documentation, it seems that one needs to initialize the Swarm with a fixed number of instances/hosts. Then, the scheduling/deployment of containers will be started on those instances based on certain criteria. I was wondering if it has the capability to scale up/down hosts. For example, let's say the Swarm starts with 3 worker hosts. And I'd like there to be a maximum of 2 containers per host. On the 7th container, I'd like for a 4th host to be created automatically. Is this possible?

It seems Amazon ECS is capable of doing this. In ECS it seems all we'll need to do is provide a container image and from there, ECS will take care of scaling up/down instances for you automatically. Is this true? Is ECS internally using Docker Swarm?

What are the pros/cons between Docker Swarm and ECS?

Comment: Amazon ECS does not use Docker Swarm.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know docker swarm will work on scaling the containers, you need to scale up and down the hosts.

Even ECS scaling up or down needs to be handled separately with EC2 autoscaling and load balancing using CloudWatch Alarms to check on the memory/cpu consumption of hosts.

In comparison to Swarm in AWS, it will be easier to manage ECS since it tightly integrates with other services and components such as Application Load Balancer, CloudWatch, IAM & etc.